# Error using PHP Simple HTML DOM parser

Tags: php, parsing, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

```
    if (!is_null($elements)) {          

        $embeds = array();
        foreach ($elements as $element) {

            if (trim(strip_tags($element->innertext)) == $episode_term) {
                $html2 = file_get_html($element->href);
                $elements2 = $html2->find('#streamlinks .sideleft a');
                if (!is_null($elements2)) {
                    foreach ($elements2 as $element) {
                        $html3 = file_get_html($element->href);
                        $iframe_element = $html3->find('.frame', 0);
                        if (!is_null($iframe_element)) {
                            $embed = $misc->buildEmbed($iframe_element->src);
                            if ($embed) {
                                $embeds[] = array(
                                    "embed" => $embed,
                                    "link" => $iframe_element->src,
                                    "language" => "ENG",
                                );
                            }
                        }
                    }                        
                }
            }
        }
        return $embeds;
    }
```

> `Blockquote`
>   PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function find() on a non-object in
>
> ```
>                 $elements2 = $html2->find('#streamlinks .sideleft a');
> ```

so its confusing as to what is causing this error to appear in my error log file?

Comment: where did you initialized `$html2`?

Comment: tried with file_get_contents?

Comment: i dont know much about coding

Comment: your file_get_html($element->href); returns false i think so check condition before using  $html2->find('#streamlinks .sideleft a');

Comment: is there any exception i can put or what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try to output `$element->href` befor you do the file_get_html. 
If the file_get_html can't get a page `$html2` stays uniinitialized and you can't use find on it.

Beside that you could build a check wether `$html2` is set after the file_get_html and output an error if not. I usually use something like this:

```
if($html2 == false || $html2 == NULL){
  // no html found
}else{
  // html found
}
```

Comment: `if($html2 == false || $html2 == NULL){}}else{$html2 = file_get_html($element->href);
                $elements2 = $html2->find('#streamlinks .sideleft a');`}
umean like that ?  @DocRattie

Comment: no, I mean like this:
`$html2 = file_get_html($element->href);if($html2 == false || $html2 == NULL){echo "your error msg";}else{$elements2 = $html2->find('#streamlinks .sideleft a'); ... }`

Comment: it solved the error. i mean it just like he moved forward after the error but can u tell me how i fix that ? @DocRattie

Comment: your problem seams to be, that the file_get_html can't get the accual html-file. thus I'd try  `...if($html2 == false || $html2 == NULL){echo $element->href;}...` and see what it says.

Comment: ok i will....but on Some links it collects data                                                     and by the way now the error forward to new line but it not effect my script`if (!is_null($elements2)) {`

Comment: Hello @DocRattie  i used `{echo $element->href;}` and it give me log like this  `http://www.example.comhttp://www.example.comhttp://www.example.com` etc...

Comment: is that the restult of ONE $element->href or of ALL $element->href ?

Comment: I think one loop because other links are posted perfectly. i dont know how much loops because at some point its like `http://www.example.comhttp://www.example.comhttp://www.example.comhttp://www.example.comhttp://www.example.comhttp://www.example.com`  and some point `http://www.example.comhttp://www.example.comhttp://www.example.comhttp://www.example.comhttp://www.example.comhttp://www.example.com` like that

Comment: try to edit it to `{echo $element->href."  ";}` with that you should see the gap between the links.

Comment: it can add space to log the links not fix the problem

Comment: It's only to show wether it's the right link you get or not.
If the link is right and you still get no result you have to look deeper into the file_get_html function what could cause the problem.

Comment: ok thank you so much for your help as it partially working it misses some loop but after all its getting majority links. So thank you for your help :) much appreciated .